# What's the best way to install a PECL extension (libsodium) for unit testing with Travis CI?

Tags: php, cookies, travis-ci, pecl, libsodium

I'm trying to add continuous integration to a project called [Halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite), which uses [libsodium](https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium) to encrypt cookies before storing them on the end-user's device.

However, I can't seem to get my travis.yml right. These were the issues I encountered:

1. Adding `extension=libsodium.so` did not lead to the extension being loaded (thus, class `Sodium` not found fatal errors).
2. Changing it to `extension=/path/to/libsodium.so` caused a fatal error where the PHPAPI versions mismatched.

I can run the tests locally, but I'd like to use Travis CI to help diagnose issues in pull requests.

Comment: PECL should automatically enable the extension, so you shouldn't need a config file and extension= line to enable it. Have you tried without this?

Comment: Yes. It gives a message [like this one](https://travis-ci.org/paragonie/halite_cookie/jobs/71982077#L1110-L1111) and fails to load the extension.

Comment: Stab in the dark as I can't see what's wrong: Have you tried running pecl without sudo and without the 'extension' and config file lines.

Comment: That actually worked. Care to give it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? :)

Comment: Not quite sure...you mean it works by just `pecl install`? I've just added a comment in https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-source-whitelist/pull/145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run pecl install without sudo. PECL should automatically enable the extension so you shouldn't need a config file and extension= line to enable it.